# Navigation Bar Style won't change when VC is presented modally

Tags: swift, storyboard, uikit, uinavigationbar

From a VC that is embedded in a Navigation Controller, I present a VC modally (as form sheet) which is also embedded into a Navigation Controller. I'm unable do change the Nav Bar Style of the second VC.

If I just change the segue from "Present Modally" to "Show (e.g. Push)", it does work. I also tried to put the code into ViewWillAppear, but didn't work.

In the modally presented VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
}
```

[image: VC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that for the navigation controller in the middle (see image), the bar tint for the navigation bar was set to a custom color